# How to Turn follow path off and on, on specific frames

Tags: animation

I am trying to get an array of objects to move from the ground and rise into the air then follow a circle around then land back on the ground.
Can i turn follow path on and off within the frames or is there another way to get the outcome?

Many Thanks

Comment: You can animate the evaluation time.

Comment: Or the influence of your constraint